# Why doesn't my query work? (SQL)

Tags: sql, pgadmin-4

Here is my code

```
SELECT flightid,flightdate,numseats,seatnumber,maxcapacity;
FROM flight,flightbooking,seatbooking;
```

I get and error saying:

```
"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 2: FROM flight,flightbooking,seatbooking;"
        ^
```

These are my tables

LeadCustomer (CustomerID, FirstName, Surname, BillingAddress, email)
Passenger(PassengerID, FirstName, Surname, PassportNo, Nationality, DoB)

Flight (FlightID, FlightDate, Origin, Destination, MaxCapacity, PricePerSeat)

FlightBooking (BookingID, CustomerID, FlightID, NumSeats, Status, BookingTime, TotalCost)

SeatBooking(BookingID, PassengerID, SeatNumber)

This is what i am trying to achieve

"Check the availability of seats on all flights by showing the flight ID number, flight date along with the number of booked seats, number of available seats and maximum capacity."

The software i am using is PG Admin 4.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you realize that you are doing cross join between all the three tables?

Comment: No, what should i do in this case?

Comment: at your near FROM probably means that semicolon in the select clause but I don't think your joins will work like you think

Comment: @MarkJason - Join them on related columns. If still not clear, post table schema, sample data and desired output.

Comment: I added some data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the SELECT line, that should fix it.

Try:

```
SELECT flightid, flightdate, numseats, seatnumber, maxcapacity
FROM flight, flightbooking, seatbooking;
```

Of course, I'm not sure this query will be much better. There are no JOIN conditions on these tables or WHERE clauses to filter results.

Comment: "ERROR:  column reference "flightid" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT flightid,flightdate,numseats,seatnumber,maxcapacity"

Comment: @MarkJason: That means you probably have a `flightid` column in more than one table. You will have to change your SELECT to something like `SELECT flight.flightid,...`